# Suppress Access Message to Prevent Duplicate Import from Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am importing data from Excel into an existing table in Access and want to suppress the below message.

I have tried using a multi field Index to import new records into the table and have also tried importing firstly to a Temporary table and then appending new records to the existing table.

However under both scenarios it still gives the below message pop up which I want to avoid the user seeing (as they could click yes by accident).

If I try SetWarnings = No in a macro, it just reimports all entries irrespective of whether they are duplicates or not so that doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help

Thanks

[image]

Comment: How is the data being imported?

Comment: Join your existing table and temporary table with current import by key fields using outer join and append only rows, where key fields of existing table is null. In this case you guaranteed, that the query won't try to insert records with existing key fields

Comment: You need to be proactive to anticipate duplicates and not reactive. Please show your import process (SQL?, VBA?) and table schema as there are ways to check for dups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't import the Excel data, link them.

Now you have a linked table. Use that as source in a query where you join it with the existing table.

Select only linked records that are not already present.

Change the query to an append query. This query you can run as often as you like.

When a new Excel file is received, just replace the linked file with the new file.

Answer (score 1):

This message will appear when trying to import data that violates an Index in the destination MS Access table.  Check that your Excel column data does not violate the corresponding MS Access field index settings.
If the MS Access field is set to "Required" = Yes, Null values (empty cells in Excel) will also cause the message to appear.
That's two possibilities...